# What is a word for something or someone who doesn't do what they are supposed to or what they were meant to do?

Tags: synonyms

I need a word for something or someone who doesn't do what it was supposed to. Like if an object was supposed to be embarrassing but instead people admire it... Idk a word for something like that or if there even is one... Suggestions??

Comment: Your question is poorly phrased, I think. _Irresponsible_ or _negligent_ could mean "doesn't do what they are supposed to do". What you mean to ask, I think, is a word to mean "has the opposite of its intended effect". Even then, you should provide more examples to clarify your question.

Comment: It sounds like _unexpected_. It would be nice if you can clarify what you are asking with a strong example.

Answer (score 2):

For *something* you can use **unintentional**. As in "The joke was **unintentional**".

For *somebody* you can use **negligent**. As in "Jo is **negligent**, he never does what he is told".

For both you could use **mistake**. What *somebody* did was a **mistake**. What *something* appears to mean is a *mistake*. This, for the object, can lead to mean that the person in charge of the object is to blame.